# find the total number of possible way to reach to a particular sum

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

suppose you have given a sum like : 5.
we have to find the total number of possible way to reach to 5.

### for example

1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5
2 + 1 + 1 + 1     = 5
1 + 2 + 1 + 1     = 5
1 + 1 + 2 + 1     = 5
1 + 1 + 1 + 2     = 5
2 + 2 + 1         = 5
2 + 1 + 2         = 5
1 + 2 + 2         = 5
1 + 1 + 3         = 5
1 + 3 + 1         = 5
3 + 1 + 1         = 5
2 + 3             = 5
3 + 2             = 5
1 + 4             = 5
4 + 1             = 5

### 5                 = 5

above is the total number of way to reach to a particular sum, which is nothing but : 16

Comment: look up compositions. otherwise you'd have a lot less and they would be partitions.

Comment: Related concept, if you didn't have orderings, is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), where they are called integer partitions.

Comment: 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 = 5....
1 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 5  .... is not a partitin but a composition

Answer (score 4):

By [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) the number of ordered $k-$tuples of positive integers that sum to $n$ is $\binom {n-1}{k-1}$.  It follows that your answer is $$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom {n-1}{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom {n-1}k=2^{n-1}$$

Direct Proof:  List $n$ $*'s$ with blanks between them.  There are $n-1$ blanks.  your decompositions are entirely determined by an arbitrary subset of those $n-1$ blanks.

Answer (score 4):

(Related to stars and bars, but a bit more explicit).

Represent $5$ as $u\;u\;u\;u\;u$.

Between any two $u$s you can insert or not insert a separator.  Once you have done this you will have uniquely determined an ordered sum to $5$.

For instance $u*u\;u\;u*u$ corresponds to $1+3+1$.

Or conversely, $2+3$ corresponds to $u\;u*u\;u\;u$.

Since there are $4$ different possible separators to insert or not insert, there are $2^4$ ways to do the problem.

These ideas should generalize to other numbers than $5$.